# How to make a flow chart like these ones?

Tags: chart-design

As part of improving my visual communication skills for my job I'm trying to start learning some ways to visualize information flows using tools other than Powerpoint. Does anyone have some tips for where I can learn how to make flowcharts like [this one](http://www.itworld.com/article/2941720/personal-technology/find-the-right-programming-language-to-learn-first-with-this-lord-of-the-rings-themed-flowchart.html) or this one[image: Flow chart]. Thanks!

Comment: I would use Adobe Illustrator to make those, but as far as learning _how_ to use AI, that's a bit beyond the scope of this site and will require you to research tutorials on your own.  There are also sites that will let you create flowcharts online.  I did a Google search and found [this one](https://www.draw.io/)...it seems alright, but I haven't tried it out.

Comment: There's lots of flow charting tools on the market. Your example are likely custom drawn with an illustration tool...be it Adobe Illustrator, or Inkscape, or any other number of drawing tools on the market.

Comment: If this is a new skill you are developing and don't want to invest in Illustrator, I'd highly recommend Inkscape. It's free and very good at what it does.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that could quickly and easily be created in Visio, just in case you have the full MSOffice suite.